# integrating zendframework with drupal

Tags: php, zend-framework, drupal

```
http://drupal.org/project/zend
```

I read in that link, that you can add a zendframework plugin and use zend framework. I find ZendFramework as a framework that is very badly documented (Jquery documentation is even better).. Is it worth adapting yet? where can I read on how to use Zend framework (is there a book or a site with clear examples, and that doesnt focus on using it with Zend_tool to create the MVC file structure?)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend framework is not only an MVC framework, but also a component library. You can use as many or as few of the components as you like.

The Zend documentation is excellent. You can find thorough documentation for all components here http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/.

I've managed to use ZF in drupal, however I never had much success with the Zend Framework Drupal Module. What I've done is to just put ZF on the class path - or you also set up the Auto Loader.

eg:

```
function module_init()
{
    set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__) . '/libs' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
}
```